# How to collect data programmatically for the performed network traffic on BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry

I want to get the data about when a connection from the device is established, when the connection is terminated and how many bytes were transferred (in/out).
I couldn't find proper listeners in the BB API. I found application that does this and I am wondering how this can be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at the [RadioInfo](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioInfo.html) class - there are methods in there such as `getNumberOfPacketsReceived()` and `getNumberOfPacketsSent()` that might do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Marc,
It seems that those methods return the number of the "Number of packets" in 4.x, but "Number of bytes" in 5.0. However after searchig for those methods in the net, it seems that there are to many doubts about their use. I am wondering if there are hidden or some partner APIs about this?

Comment: Is this includes 3GPP and WIFI? What does that include can you please put a code example for this ?
I need also to get all Data Transfer logs how do i do it?